# Mysqli_Query INSERT

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

For some reason, this code is not inserting into my database, It was working a few days ago, I swear. Now, nothing. Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's not working? It's just giving any errors.

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or die('Error->' .mysqli_error($con));

function quote2entities($string,$entities_type='number')
{
    $search                     = array("\"","'");
    $replace_by_entities_name   = array("&quot;","&apos;");
    $replace_by_entities_number = array("&#34;","&#39;");
    $do = null;
    if ($entities_type == 'number')
    {
        $do = str_replace($search,$replace_by_entities_number,$string);
    }
    else if ($entities_type == 'name')
    {
        $do = str_replace($search,$replace_by_entities_name,$string);
    }
    else
    {
        $do = addslashes($string);
    }
    return $do;
}
echo mysqli_error($con);

$c = quote2entities($_POST['company']);
$mem = quote2entities($mem);
$cp = quote2entities($cp);
$vcc = quote2entities($vcc);
$addy = quote2entities($addy);
$contact = quote2entities($contact);
$date = quote2entities($date);
$type = quote2entities($type);


echo $c ;
echo $contact;
echo $vcc;
$query = "INSERT INTO project (company) VALUES (".$c.")";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Have you changed server?

Comment: Did you happen to change this `('Error->'`? that `>` could be playing tricks on you.

Comment: also change `VALUES (".$c.")` to `VALUES ('".$c."')` could be another thing

Comment: let me try the ('".$c."') again, it was set there before. I don't know, also ('Error->' is set using literal terms, so that isn't the problem. @Fred -ii-

Comment: Of course, that was the issue, I have no idea why that is required though. Thanks anyways! If you post it as a comment I'll make it the answer!

Comment: @RainbowdashTM The `VALUES ('".$c."')` or `('Error->'` ?

Comment: Not using bound parameters... Not checking return value from mysqli_query()... Not printing any error messages... Come on, this has been answered hundreds of times on StackOverflow already.

Answer (score 1):

Change `VALUES (".$c.")` to `VALUES ('".$c."')`

the variable needs to be inclosed inside single quotes.

You also could use single quotes `('$c')` or `('.$c.')` as other options.

These I already knew, however you can consult: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/1415724) 
to see the different combinations.

Answer (score 1):

This code should never ever be used.
As it makes not a slightest sense: for some reason you are using **HTML** encoding when dealing with **database.** Which is obviously wrong. Not to mention that you ought to use prepared statements instead of interpolating values into query.

Please get rid of your current approach and learn the right way here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)